# Do I have to disclose all academic history?

Tags: undergraduate

I'd like to go back to school for a BS in Physics but most universities don't admit students who already hold degrees.
My first time around I was not academically mature and only pulled a 3.0 for my first BS in Mathematics.

If I rebuilt some class history through a community college and then try to transfer to a full university can I avoid telling them I have a degree?

And are there consequences for trying to hide that information?

I would try a different method but the options seem extremely limited for someone holding a bachelors who wants a second bachelors and can't get up and move to a university that allows it.

Comment: What do you want to do with that BS in Physics?

Comment: See http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/14983/1010.  Short answers: Yes, you have to; no, you cannot avoid it; yes, there are consequences.

Comment: IMHO, you should not bother with a second BS.  Contact the place where you want to get the physics degree and find out if there are certain deficiency courses you should take to be able to apply to the M.S. in Physics, take these over the summer, then apply to the M.S. program.  Math is a rather reasonable degree to serve as passage to a Physics M.S. program.  Also, as mentioned by other commenters, most schools will ask you for your transcripts and it would be fraud not to submit them.