# Failed in PhD candidacy and applying to a new graduate school

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose

I failed in PhD candidacy and planning to apply in a new graduate school. Should I mention or hide the failure in my SOP as it is a negative in my profile. Please help

Comment: Others that may be relevant or even possibly better: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107351/what-would-be-the-possible-consequence-of-concealing-an-incomplete-degree https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14971/academic-dismissal-from-phd-program-what-next/14983